# Google sheets how do I ensure field change done before running script with button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a button (drawing) that executes an apps script. The script reads the data on the sheet and does some work.

I keep making the same mistake. I change some data in a cell then push the button. Since the cell only saves on lost focus, and the button push does not cause a change of focus, the data has not actually changed. I have to make the change to the field, click on another field then push the button. There does not seem to be anyway to save all changes before the button press.

How can I detect that I am mid edit and save what I have first then run my script.  Or is there a way to disable the button until edit is done?

Comment: There is no mid-onEdit trigger that I know of. But perhaps you could use the onEdit trigger and dispense with pushing the button.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I change some data then push the button and Since I have not left the Field the data has not actually changed and the results are not what I expect. I have to make the change to the field, click on another field then push the button.`. Especially, I cannot understand about `Field`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: let me try editing the question see if I can make it clearer

Answer (score 4):

Here is some sample code to implement checkbox buttons.

Use **Insert > Checkbox** to place checkboxes in cells, then specify the location of a checkbox in the `cellToWatch` parameter, and give the name of the function to run when that checkbox is ticked through the `action.run` parameter.

You can specify multiple checkboxes by including more objects in the `triggers` array.

```
/**
* Checkbox buttons
*
* Use Insert > Checkbox instead of Insert > Drawing
* to implement clickable buttons in Google Sheets.
*
* Checkboxes work in Sheets on mobile as well as Sheets on web.
* Functions run this way work without explicit end-user authorization,
* but in a limited access mode where they cannot call services that
* require authorization.
*
* @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67160138/13045193
*/


/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  checkboxButtons_(e);
}


/**
* Runs a function when a cell value changes.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function checkboxButtons_(e) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 19 April 2021
  //  - generalize
  try {
    const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    const triggers = [

      ////////////////////////////////
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        description: 'Shows a message when the checkbox in Sheet1!B2 is ticked.',
        cellToWatch: e.source.getRange('Sheet1!B2'),
        triggerValue: true,
        resetValue: false,
        action: {
          run: exampleFunction_,
          parameters: {
            exampleMessage: "It's alive!",
          },
        },
        messagePost: '',
        event: e,
      },
      {
        description: 'Clears some cells when the checkbox in Sheet1!B3 is ticked.',
        cellToWatch: e.source.getRange('Sheet1!B3'),
        triggerValue: true,
        resetValue: false,
        action: {
          run: exampleFunctionClearRanges_,
          parameters: {
            rangeListToClear: sheet.getRangeList(['C7', 'E7', 'G7', 'C8', 'E8', 'G8']),
          },
        },
        messagePost: 'Cleared six cells.',
        event: e,
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]
      ////////////////////////////////

    ];
    triggers.some(function (trigger) {
      if (sheet.getSheetId() !== trigger.cellToWatch.getSheet().getSheetId()
        || e.range.getA1Notation() !== trigger.cellToWatch.getA1Notation()
        || e.range.getValue() !== trigger.triggerValue) {
        return false;
      }
      trigger.action.run(trigger.action.parameters, trigger);
      trigger.cellToWatch.setValue(trigger.resetValue);
      if (trigger.messagePost) {
        showMessage_(trigger.messagePost);
      }
      return true;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    showAndThrow_(error);
  }
}


/**
* Example function that shows a message in a toast.
*
* @param {Object} parameters The trigger.action.parameters object from checkboxButtons_().
* @param {Object} event The event object from checkboxButtons_().
* @return {Object} The original event object, for chaining.
*/
function exampleFunction_(parameters, event) {
  showMessage_(parameters.exampleMessage);
  return event;
}


/**
* Example function that clears all ranges in a range list in one go.
*
* @param {Object} parameters The trigger.action.parameters object from checkboxButtons_().
* @param {Object} event The event object from checkboxButtons_().
* @return {Object} The original event object, for chaining.
*/
function exampleFunctionClearRanges_(parameters, event) {
  parameters.rangeListToClear.clearContent();
  return event;
}


/**
* Shows error.message in a pop-up and throws the error.
*
* @param {Error} error The error to show and throw.
*/
function showAndThrow_(error) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  var stackCodeLines = String(error.stack).match(/\d+:/);
  if (stackCodeLines) {
    var codeLine = stackCodeLines.join(', ').slice(0, -1);
  } else {
    codeLine = error.stack;
  }
  showMessage_(error.message + ' Code line: ' + codeLine, 30);
  throw error;
}


/**
* Shows a message in a pop-up.
*
* @param {String} message The message to show.
* @param {Number} timeoutSeconds Optional. The number of seconds before the message goes away. Defaults to 5.
*/
function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'Checkbox buttons', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **checkbox** to trigger the function using `onEdit(e)`, this way you are forced to unselect the input cell before running the function.

Or you can keep using the button, but checking that the checkbox is selected, otherwise the function returns a warning message or something.

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable work around. I can have a checkbox "I have verified the fields" that needs to be checked before script will run.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to have the button just select a hidden checkbox which runs the code using the onEdit script?

I'm not sure if onEdit would trigger and I'm also not sure if the selected field would un-select but it seems to be worth a try.

Comment: No events get triggered when the spreadsheet is modified by a script. The `onEdit(e)` simple trigger only runs when the user hand edits a range.

Comment: So annoying! Surely they have to have a way around this, what's the point in having buttons if they don't always work :(