# I own several GS spreadsheets, with button-activated scripts. Can I give users permission to use them, without those users sacrificing their security?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is the best way for me to accomplish the following outcome? I would be extremely grateful for any help that you can offer.

---

I am the owner of ten Google Sheets spreadsheets. And I want to share those ten spreadsheets with several users, such that each user is able to do the following: when the user opens spreadsheet S1, and presses button B, then it runs a script that reads and modifies the cell-values in spreadsheet S2.

I have created a working prototype, but it has one major flaw that I don't want the final version to have. See, I don't want the user to have to go through a scary-looking permission screen when he clicks a button for the first time... after all, this button is located in a document that I own, and it modifies a document that I own... there is absolutely no reason for the user to give *me* permission for anything.

---

I am 100% sure that it's possible to do this, since I own all of the spreadsheets and no permissions from the user should be required (after all, I am the one granting the user access to *my* files, not the other way around). But I am stumped as to how to learn *how*... could you pretty please help me with this problem?

Comment: I think you should come to the conclusion that that 100% is more like 0%. You need edit rights for the script. Therefore you can modify the script. Is does not matter if you own the sheet. You can write an function to get the gmail from the current user and delete all there contacts., or the root Drive from the current user... ect.. So permissions is absolutely  required....

Comment: Assuming that the Apps Script code is only accessing your account, you can implement a two step process to make *most* of the code inaccessible to the user, and still have it run without asking for permission.  If the code needs to do *anything* with the users account, then there is no way around asking for permission.  The code bound to the Sheet could just have the minimum needed, and call your Web App with a POST request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(published_url_of_your_web_app)` and your web app can then get the Sheet by ID.  Pass the Sheet file ID to the Web App.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question to only refer to the flaw that I was most worried about... namely, that my script always asks for permission to see and delete all of the spreadsheets in each user's Google Drive. Which is a very scary thing for my users to see, of course. I mean, my users trust me well enough, but not with unreasonable stuff like *that*, sheesh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One recipe to avoid showing users the authorization dialog box is to run your code through a trigger. This would require that users start a script by clicking a checkbox instead of clicking a button. See the [checkboxButtons_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67160138/13045193) script for an example. Note that this recipe will not in itself let you make the code inaccessible to users.

You are saying that your code needs to access another spreadsheet. This means that you cannot use the `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) but need to run the code under your own account through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Another recipe is to implement your script as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and deploy it as "run as me". The code will then run under your account, regardless of who the user at the keyboard is. This lets you keep the code to yourself, but the user interface will then be HTML based within the web app, and the spreadsheet just acts as the back end.

See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153204/embed-an-interactive-calculator-in-my-website-using-google-sheets) answer for more information and sample code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just one question...   can the user still click the buttons inside the spreadsheet, when the script is a web app? Or do all web apps have to be a webpage that is separate from the spreadsheet?

Comment: You may want to read a bit about Google's [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) system.

Comment: Edited the answer to include another potential recipe to avoid the authorization dialog box.