# Google Sheets: Checkbox button that auto-FALSE right after checking

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a form of a button using the checkbox feature in Google Sheets. The use of it is to act as a button to roll a random number.

I have everything else figured out and situated, however I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this checkbox to act as a button.

I simply would like for it to uncheck a few milliseconds after it's been checked. from False > True > False.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may want to see the [checkboxButtons_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67160138/13045193) script.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well unsderstood your requirement

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(sheet.getName()=='mySheet' && editedCell.getA1Notation()=='A1'){  
    if (editedCell.getValue()){ 
      // do something
      editedCell.setValue(!editedCell.getValue())
    }
  }
}
```